# Triangulating a Planar Polygon

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom

Are there by now simpler algorithms/proofs for triangulating a planar polygon in linear time? What is a good resource on the state of the art of this famous problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far, the only improvement to [Chazelle's juggernaut](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02574703) is the 2001 randomized linear-time algorithm by [Amato, Goodrich, and Ramos](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-001-0027-x).  Chazelle's algorithm is still the only deterministic O(n)-time triangulation algorithm known.